# Force connection close lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, http-headers

I have a M2M project that sends out the following headers.

```
HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: zh-cn
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
RANGE:bytes=0-1023
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Apache and ISS have `connection : close` in the response headers, regardless of the request to `keep-alive`.  Lighttpd I assume is actually performing correctly as it does keep the connection alive, or does not send a `connection : close`. I actually need it to close the connection for the M2M machine to work. I tried

```
 setenv.add-response-header = ( "connection" => "close" )
```

But this is ignored, anyway to force a connection close?

Answer (score 0):

Setting [server.max-keep-alive-requests](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server.max-keep-alive-requestsDetails) to 0 should cause Lighttpd to close the connection after each request.

```
server.max-keep-alive-requests = 0
```